# How do you test a custom expectation?

Tags: r, testthat

Suppose I want a custom `testthat` expectation.  For example, I'm testing lots of objects to see if they have no missing values.  The `testhat` way of writing things should be something like this:

```
expect_no_nas <- function(object, info = NULL, label = NULL)
{
  lab <- testthat:::make_label(object, label)
  expect(has_no_nas(object), sprintf("%s has nulls.", lab), 
    info = info)
  invisible(object)
}

has_no_nas <- function()
{
  !any(is.na(x))
}
```

How do I test that that is right?

I can write tests that pass, no problem.

```
test_that(
  "expect_no_nas passes when there are no NAs",
  {
    expect_no_nas(1:5)
  }
)
```

I thought I could wrap the custom expectation in `expect_error`, but this doesn't work:

```
test_that(
  "expect_no_nas fails when there are NAs",
  {
    expect_error(expect_no_nas(c(1, NA)))
  }
)   
## Error: Test failed: 'expect_no_nas fails when there are NAs'
## * Not expected: c(1, NA) has NAs.
## * Not expected: expect_no_nas(c(1, NA)) code raised an error.
```

Wrapping it in `try` doesn't work either.

```
test_that(
  "expect_no_nas fails when there are NAs",
  {
    res <- try(expect_no_nas(c(1, NA)))
    expect_false(res$passed)
  }
) 
## Error: Test failed: 'expect_no_nas fails when there are NAs'
## Not expected: c(1, NA) has NAs.
```

How do I test for the failing cases?  (The important thing to remember is that we are testing whether `expect_no_nas` works, not just writing tests that use `expect_no_nas`.)

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled... what would be your expected output? The function gives an error when there are NAs... as it is supposed to, or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes, `expect_no_nas` is supposed to give an error when there are NAs.  But since I want to test the `expect_no_nas` function, I want a meta test.  That is, a (passing) test that tests that `expect_no_nas` failed correctly.  Re-reading that, I see why you are puzzled.

Comment: OK, now I see what you mean!

Answer (score 6):

Nico's query help clarify things:  you need a test inside a test.

```
test_that(
  "expect_no_nas fails when there are NAs",
  {
    expect_error(
      test_that(
        "failing test",
        {
          expect_no_nas(c(1, NA))
        }
      ) 
    )
  }
)
```